# ¿En que está equivocada mi sentencia SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
insert into registrohora (id, rutpaciente, rutemple, hora_actual, fecha_actual, estado, fecha_atencion, hora_atencion)
values ('', '19589826-K', '11.594.304-8', '16:57:06', '2019-12-19', '1', '2019-12-26', '1'
(select * from registrohora where not hora_atencion = '1' and fecha_atencion = '2019-12-26'))
```

En base a esto, lo que quiero hacer es que quiero insertar datos con la condición de que el id de hora_atención no haya sido ocupada en tal fecha_atencion.

Pero aun así cuando trato de ejecutarla en mySQL no me deja y aparece un error de sintaxis, si alguien pudiera ayudarme a saber por que está mal mi sentencia y si fuera posible rehacerla con lo que necesito.

Post data:

asi es la estructura de la tabla registrohora

```
CREATE TABLE `registrohora` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `rutpaciente` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rutemple` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hora_actual` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_actual` date NOT NULL,
  `estado` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_atencion` date NOT NULL,
  `hora_atencion` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Agrega el error de sintaxis por favor

Comment: #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '(select * from registrohora where not hora_atencion = '1' and fecha_atencion = '' en la linea 3 @Aprendiz

Answer (score 0):

te falta una `,` luego del `'1'` en los values

```
insert into registrohora (id, rutpaciente, rutemple, hora_actual, fecha_actual, estado, fecha_atencion, hora_atencion)
values ('', '19589826-K', '11.594.304-8', '16:57:06', '2019-12-19', '1', '2019-12-26', '1',
(select * from registrohora where not hora_atencion = '1' and fecha_atencion = '2019-12-26'))

> #1241 - Operando debe tener 1 columna(s)
```

también debes cambiar el `*` que tienes en la subquery, ya que en la columna solo puedes insertar un valor, y al poner `*` es como si quisieras insertar la fila entera en la columna `hora_atencion` por ejemplo

```
insert into registrohora (id, rutpaciente, rutemple, hora_actual, fecha_actual, estado, fecha_atencion, hora_atencion)
values ('', '19589826-K', '11.594.304-8', '16:57:06', '2019-12-19', '1', '2019-12-26', '1',
(select hora_atencion from registrohora where not hora_atencion = '1' and fecha_atencion = '2019-12-26'))

> #1136 - El número de columnas no corresponde al número en la línea 1
```

Queda igualar el numero de columnas arriba y abajo

Comment: Esa coma faltaba aunque al ejecutarla, un nuevo error me aparece: #1241 - Operando debe tener 1 columna(s)

Comment: Solo falta que cambies el `*` por el campo que quieres sacar de la tabla registrohora, modifique mi respuesta dándote un ejemplo

Comment: #1136 - El número de columnas no corresponde al número en la línea 1 cuando lo tento de esta forma `insert into registrohora (id, rutpaciente, rutemple, hora_actual, fecha_actual, estado, fecha_atencion, hora_atencion)
values ('6', '19589826-K', '11.594.304-8', '16:57:06', '2019-12-19', '1', '2019-12-26', '1',
(select fecha_atencion from registrohora where not hora_atencion = '1' and fecha_atencion = '2019-12-26'))` @Victor Alvarez

Comment: tienes 8 columnas declaradas en el `insert into` pero le estas mandando 9 valores, te falta agregar alguna columna arriba o quitar un valor abajo?

Comment: Si quito '6' (como anteriormente puse en la sentencia), me aparece aquel error: #1093 - Table 'registrohora' is specified twice, both as a target for 'INSERT' and as a separate source for data, Así es como dejé mi sentencia: `insert into registrohora (id, rutpaciente, rutemple, hora_actual, fecha_actual, estado, fecha_atencion, hora_atencion)
values ('19589826-K', '11.594.304-8', '16:57:06', '2019-12-19', '1', '2019-12-26', '1', (select fecha_atencion from registrohora where not hora_atencion = '1' and fecha_atencion = '2019-12-26'))`, la columna id es incremental por si acaso

Comment: El detalle es que eliminaste '6' que correspondía a la columna id, eso hace que los valores se vayan a insertar en una columna que no son, revisa con cuidado que todos los valores estén en su lugar correctamente

Answer (score 0):

Es que creo que se lia al hacer el SELECT en la misma instruccion que al crear el SCHEMA. Es decir, yo haria por una lado:

```
CREATE TABLE `registrohora` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `rutpaciente` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rutemple` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hora_actual` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_actual` date NOT NULL,
  `estado` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_atencion` date NOT NULL,
  `hora_atencion` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert into registrohora (id, rutpaciente, rutemple, hora_actual, fecha_actual, estado, fecha_atencion, hora_atencion)
values ('1', '19589826-K', '11.594.304-8', '16:57:06', '2019-12-19', '1', '2019-12-26', '1')
```

Y por otro lado esto:

```
select * from registrohora where not hora_atencion = '1' and fecha_atencion = '2019-12-26'
```

Aunque creo que mas bien haria esto para comprobar que me devuelve el registro que acabo de meter:

```
select * from registrohora where hora_atencion = '1' and fecha_atencion = '2019-12-26'
```